# Why do we have the [math] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Why do we have the math tag when Stack Overflow is about programming?

Questions with the math tag almost always get closed for being off-topic.

Why do we still have the math tag? What purpose does this tag serve but to attract more off-topic questions?

---

Reasons:

- The [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) tag isn't necessary because it is always coupled with another tag for Python, C++ or Java. Also if a question's only tag is the math tag it is almost always going to be closed.
- The math tag's only purpose has been to encourage people to ask off-topic questions.
- The [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) tag has **only** been on-topic when there is another tag proving that the Math tag itself is not necessary in the question.
- The [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math) tag doesn't help the question asker in any way to clarify what the question is about, thus proving that the math tag doesn't serve any beneficial purpose at all.

---

My list of reasons prove how the math tag isn't necessary in any question. It doesn't help clarify the question and the math tag itself only exist to increase the amount of off-topic questions in addition to the already large amount of off-topic questions.

Burnination of the math tag would be a boon for Stack Overflow and all of us.

**Four out of five of these example questions have been asked recently:**

- *[Given a point and distance, is it possible to get the second point on the line + three dimensional points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28380578)*
- *[What is the meaning of "integral length sides" and "integral area"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17630613) ([screenshot for <10k users in case the question gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbrmC.png))*
- *[To find a number which can have only 3 or 5 as its digit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28371372)*
- *[Finding recursive formula for sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28351075)*
- *[How To Find The Length Of An Irregular Arc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28349734) ([screenshot for <10k users in case the question gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYsxE.png))*

Comment: That's a nice assortment of useless questions.  I voted to close or delete every one of them.  But I still don't agree with your premise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are [19,194](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmath%5D+is%3Aquestion) questions tagged with [math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/math). Only [2015](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmath%5D+is%3Aquestion+closed%3Ayes) of them are closed.

There are many perfectly valid questions on SO that are about programming and math. Questions just about math should be closed though.

Comment: you still don't need that math tag because the questions tagged with math aslo had other tags

Comment: "Questions just about math should be closed though." I read that as "Questions with only [tag:math] should be closed though." Isn't that the definition of [a meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)?

Comment: @KevinBrown No.  From the link:  **The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question.** (emphasis in original).  `math` does describe an aspect of the content.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson Are you saying that questions should have but one tag, or that only certain aspects of the question should be reflected in tags, or something else entirely?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I was referring to "If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.", though I do believe that it wouldn't be reasonable to burn [tag:math], if only for the fact that there are 19k questions.