# Can we make the Close Votes review queue more efficient?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close

Something similar has probably been asked before, but apparently noting or not enough has been done. So please don't close this as a duplicate before my should be closed flags stop ageing away.

At the moment I'm writing this, the Close Votes review queue has 8.6k questions pending, which is more than 40 times more than in the other review queues. And as far as I can remember, every time I've visited the review page the Close Votes review queue has had a lot more pending questions than any other queue. This leads to that questions that should be closed are never closed. Here are a few examples:

- I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41696582/4284627) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JChZL.png)) as blatantly off-topic and my flag aged away. So I flagged it for moderator attention and it got closed by a moderator 19 days after it was asked.
- I flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349734/how-to-find-the-length-of-an-irregular-arc) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYsxE.png)) as blatantly off topic 4 times, all those flags aged away. I finally flagged it for moderator attention and a moderator closed it over one year and two months after is was asked. And according to [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285606/why-have-the-math-tag#comment152981_285606), someone else voted to close that question a year before I flagged it, and apparently that close vote also expired.

These are just two examples of all my should be closed flags that aged away. Out of a total of 308 should be closed flags, 104 aged away, which is 34%. The only reason why the two above questions were handled was because I felt strongly enough that they should be closed that I went back and flagged them for moderator attention once my flags aged away. But you can't expect everyone to do that, so I wouldn't be surprised if there are a lot of questions out there that have nothing to do with programming (or should be closed for any other reason), and that are still open.

For these reasons, I suggest we do something to reduce the size of the Close Votes review queue. Here are a few suggestions:

- Increase the maximum number of close vote reviews per day from 40 to for example 100. Also do so that close votes from the Close Votes review queue don't count towards the daily limit of close votes.
- Let users who don't have the privilege to vote to close review close votes. The Close Votes review could then work like the Low Quality Posts review works. In Low Quality Posts, users with more than 2000 reputation can recommend deletion on a post although they don't have the privilege to vote to delete. Similarly, we could let users with for example 1000 reputation review close votes and if they don't have the privilege to vote to close, they can recommend close. If necessary, reviews from such users could count less than a close vote from a 3k user. For example, two "recommend close" reviews could count as one close vote.

I'm not asking that one of these specific suggestions gets implemented, I'm asking that something should be done to make the Close Votes review more efficient. These are just suggestions on how to do this. If you have other ideas, feel free to suggest them.

I really think that something should be done to make the Close Votes review more efficient. Normally, questions like the two I mentioned should be closed within a few hours after they were asked. If that's not the case, something is wrong.

Comment: Your second bullet has some merit, your first has not as that has been tried before and didn't help a bit. The second bullet actually brings more people  in the queue that is what we should be looking for. Worth mentioning that for obvious close vote cases that might go unnoticed or will not get handled in an organic way you can try to seek assistance in chat. [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) is a room that is open for cv-pls requests on active questions.

Comment: Efforts to make review queues more efficient are like taking an aspirin for the pain in your foot, which just got torn off by a bear. You're treating a symptom of a symptom. The problem is not going to be solved by handling questions after they're posted. The way to improve is to make it harder to ask bad/off-topic questions.