# How to encourage users to do reviews?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I've noticed lately that the Review button is emphasized on the menu bar at the top. I clicked on it and saw that almost 10.000 items are in the queue.

I remember that when reviewing first came out I did it a lot but now I don't review posts at all. I don't know what would motivate me to do it again but I think that the topic might worth a discussion. These are the things that came into mind:

- Lower the cap for close votes from 5. It is annoying when an answer/question is clearly out of place but I can't just close it with a click. (I know that if I get 1000 upvotes I become a moderator for a topic)
- Give reputation for reviewing
- Make reviews count towards a specialization in the given technology (for example if I get 1000 upvotes in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), I'll become a Java moderator. Reviewing might count towards that goal

Comment: Not that I disagree that we could use more reviewers, but the proposed solutions are not something I'd like to see implemented. There is also a misconception in the first one (gold badgers can only close immediately on duplicates).

Comment: There is a complete chatroom, SOCVR, for that queue. Did help only a tiny bit  but not to get it solved...

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @rene "Did help" - wait, are you saying it no longer does? :)

Comment: @JonClements  oh no, it is just that our focus got broader, so it is not just a weekly event to burn that queue down.

Comment: It still works.  I use SOCVR to run me out of votes by early evening, so I get nights off from the trash.

Comment: for context: this is where SOCVR started from: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251955/so-close-vote-reviewers

Comment: These UI changes are just a carrot on a stick.  They need 3000 new users every week to keep up with the lossage.  Users on average don't last for more than a month before they give up in disgust or get review-banned.  It is pretty horrible galley slave duty with no tangible benefits and no discernable improvement on the site.  This doesn't get truly better until the company recognizes that this is a finite resource and they can't just keep dumping boxes of legos on the floor and expect them to be picked up every time.  Which is not that hard to do, some queues are truly a waste of time.

Comment: We really really really really need to increase the *weight* of close votes coming from gold (and possibly silver) tag badge holders. It should not take 5 Java experts to close a Java question as "too broad" or "unclear what you're asking" or "lacks repro code".

Comment: @CodyGray FWIW [increasing amount of votes in "their" tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240702/165773) would work the same as increasing weight, "...perhaps 5 at the bronze level, so people can actually do _stuff_ right away. Then perhaps 15 more at the silver level, which becomes even _more_ useful when you hit gold and unlock the other ability. When folks hit the bronze level, the extra votes will almost _always_ come on the heels of unlocking another privilege just through rep, so this could be a really good way of bringing out even more enthusiasm for that achievement as well."

Comment: More votes would only allow those who hit the cap to do more, but that's a relatively small percentage as it is.

Comment: I'd rather make the review queues less needed. They aren't fun or engaging, and promotes people approving(or disapproving) things incorrectly. Instead, Maybe we should limit suggested edits by rep a bit stricter, increase the weight of close votes and reopen votes in some way (whether it be a global 3 votes rather than 5, or if we expand the dupe hammer to other close reasons, etc) and then adjust from there.

Answer (score 6):

1. *Moderator for a topic* is actually a dupe hammer which allows you to mark question as a duplicate on your own. It doesn't allow you to close with different reasons.
2. Lowering the cap for close votes from 5 might be worth being considered but not in case it's applied for review queues - robo reviewers are really an issue.
3. Awarding reputation for reviewing might increase the amount of robo-reviewers again.

Answer (score 2):

> - Lower the cap for close votes from 5. It is annoying when an answer/question is clearly out of place but I can't just close it with a click. (I know that if I get 1000 upvotes I become a moderator for a topic)

Being able to close a question with only one click should only be allowed to users who exactly know what they're doing and I think it is implemented good enough right now. Lowering the cap to maybe 3 votes might be worth considering, though.

> - Give reputation for reviewing

Sounds like a bad idea. We get reputation for asking good questions and giving good answers (oh, and editing, but this too falls mainly under the "questions/answers" section. Plus, reputation gained from editing is limited).

> - Make reviews count towards a specialization in the given technology (for example if I get 1000 upvotes in java, I'll become a Java moderator. Reviewing might count towards that goal

That doesn't sound too bad, but I'm not knowledable enough in that topic to give a really good opinion here.

---

Some things that came to my mind:

- Lower the reputation caps for queues with a big backlog.
  Maybe lower the reputation needed to start reviewing the Close Votes queue to 2000, this would give more users the chance to start doing their share of the workload. Maybe this can be done even temporarily.
- Award review badges more than once
  I just very recently got my gold badge in the First Posts queue, and I don't know how long I will stay motivated to do reviews there (not that it's really needed, though. The queue is emptied really quickly anyway). I see users in the Close Votes queue with over 50k reviews done. While I appreciate their efforts, wouldn't it be nice if the community as a whole would appreciate it and at least give those users some more badges?

Answer (score 1):

> - Lower the cap for close votes from 5. It is annoying when an answer/question is clearly out of place but I can't just close it with a click. (I know that if I get 1000 upvotes I become a moderator for a topic)

Allowing anyone to close any question with one click isn't a good idea, since it could lead to abuse. Lowering the cap to 3 or 4 close votes may not be such a bad idea, but I don't know if it would do much good. Questions that get that many close votes usually get higher priority in the review queue and get closed anyway. Also, I think you misunderstood a bit what happens when you earn a gold tag badge. Earning a gold tag badge doesn't really make you a moderator for the topic, it only allows you to close questions as duplicates on your own in that tag. Your close vote for any other reason still counts as a normal close vote. It might be a good idea to let gold tag badge holders close questions in that tag as anything though (but that would still not make them moderators, since they would for example still not be able to delete posts on their own, and I don't see the need to allow them to do so).

> - Give reputation for reviewing

Absolutely not. There are already big problems with robo-reviewers (they approve suggested edits that are clearly wrong, they vote to leave open questions that should definitely be closed, etc), and that's just for the badges. I'm sure it would be a lot worse if they got reputation for reviewing. Users need to be encouraged to review *correctly*, not to just click on "Looks OK" or "Approve" until they hit the daily limit just to get rewards (badges or reputation).

> - Make reviews count towards a specialization in the given technology (for example if I get 1000 upvotes in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), I'll become a Java moderator. Reviewing might count towards that goal.

Again, "moderator" isn't the correct term here. You're talking about tag badges and the dupehammer privilege that goes with them. There are already badges for reviewing, so making reviews count against tag badges isn't necessary. On the contrary, there will be more robo-reviewers if they more badges for reviewing. Not to mention users who want to get a gold tag badge to be able to use the dupehammer.

---

**Solutions that may work**

- Taken from my question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349542/4284627):

  > Let users who don't have the privilege to vote to close review close votes. The Close Votes review could then work like the Low Quality Posts review works. In Low Quality Posts, users with more than 2000 reputation can recommend deletion on a post although they don't have the privilege to vote to delete. Similarly, we could let users with for example 1000 reputation review close votes and if they don't have the privilege to vote to close, they can recommend close. If necessary, reviews from such users could count less than a close vote from a 3k user. For example, two "recommend close" reviews could count as one close vote.
- Your idea to allow gold tag badge holders to close a question on their own for any reason, not only duplicates, might also help (though I'm not sure that's what you meant). There are a lot of question that get one close vote and then nothing more and the close vote ages away. If that close vote is from a user with a gold badge in a tag on the question, allowing gold tag badge holders to close questions on their own would help. It would't help for questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41696582/4284627) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JChZL.png)) that have nothing to do with programming since not may users have a gold tag badge in [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) (and even if they did, they wouldn't really deserve it since [the [history] tag is ambiguous](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343030/4284627)). But it might help for "give me the code" or "debug my 500 lines of code for me" questions since those questions are usually tagged in popular tags.
- Award badges for *correct* reviewing. The main reason why your ideas of giving users awards for reviewing a lot is because it would encourage fast (and therefore often incorrect) reviewing. Giving badges for correct reviewing might be a solution. The only problem is that I'm not sure how to implement it. Awarding badges for passing review audits may seem like a solution, but then users would just create bots to detect audits, which would make the situation even worse. Maybe only reviews where the user reviewed the same way as the consensus could count towards the badge, but the problem is that the majority isn't always right, especially not when there are robo-reviewers. If someone has an idea about how to award badges for correct reviewing in a way that's accurate and difficult to abuse, great, I recommend you suggest them, but I don't really have any ideas that would work well.